# Reload Startup File Causes Blender to Stop Responding

Tags: shortcut, startup-file

Whenever I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to reload my startup file, Blender stops responding for about a minute. If I use File> Reload Startup File it works instantly. I personally prefer using the shortcut, so this is rather annoying.

Is there a specific reason that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> would take longer?

Windows 10, Blender 2.77a

Answer (score 1):

use "*file*" -> "*load factory settings*", followed by "*file*" -> "*save startup file*".

the reason it's slow because you may have changed your startup file to a custom blend file that uses alot of memory.

Comment: I would agree that a custom startup file could use more memory, but I really don't want to reset it. I'm merely asking why the hotkey takes longer.

Comment: It might be worth trying this after backing up your preferred startup file, just to see if it's your startup file causing the problem or something else. I know that sounds strange because we'd expect the shortcut and menu command to be doing the same exact thing, but there may be some difference under the hood.